# How to use count and row_number in java spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, group-by

I want to fetch the data in JPA Spring Boot from database using cast and count function, but my data is not returning any ID. So, I creating new field that returning auto number using `row_number()` in SQL.

I'm getting a problem in JPA Spring Boot to fetch the data using row_number,

here is my SQL Syntax

```
select row_number () over() as id,
cast (t.create_datetime as date) as reportDate,
count(*) as totalTransaction 
from vx_transaction."transaction" t
group by cast(t.create_datetime as date)
```

the result in databases is as expected

[Result in DBEAVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glgvg.png)

but, I'm getting error in JPA Spring

> ERROR: column "t.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in
> an aggregate function

Then, I'm trying to fix the problem with adding the id in group by. Here's the code

```
select row_number () over() as id,
cast (t.create_datetime as date) as reportDate,
count(*) as totalTransaction 
from vx_transaction."transaction" t
group by cast(t.create_datetime as date), id
```

There is not error, but..... the result not as expected

[Not as expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYMP0.png)

Can anyone help me to solve this problem??